# VisualStudio 2017 multiple "Keep Target Branch Version"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution

After some changes I've to merge the master branch in a dev branch where we deleted tons of files, so the "Resolve Conflicts" page lists all of them and it seems I should process each and every conflict choosing "Keep Target Branch Version". Since they are around 4k of them, is there any way to select all the conflicts I want to be kept from the target branch and resolve them with few clicks? FYI the code is on VSTS. My only alternative I think is could be to delete the 4k files in the master (source) branch as well and then merge into the dev (target) one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the version control system do you use, Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below ways to achieve that:

- **Select all** (select the first item, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the last item.) then click "`Keep Target Branch Version`".
- Another way is using the [Resolve Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/6yw3tcdy(v=vs.100)):

  `tf resolve ..... /auto:TakeTheirs` will "`Take Source Branch Version`." My suggestion is to do the resolve, then check your branch
  and make sure that you have what you expect before you check in.

  `tf resolve .... /auto:KeepYours`  will "`Keep Target Branch Version`"

  Following below steps to do that:

  1. Merger from one branch to another from Visual Studio (Conflicts
     appear)
  2. Open cmd console `Developer Command Prompt for VS2017`
  3. cd to workspace location
  4. Run below command (It will prompt the dialog to enter your credential to login VSTS):

     `tf resolve /auto:KeepYours`

[image]